# Wordpress ajax is not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to execute update query through wordpress ajax , here is my code :

**on plugin page :**

```
<tr>
                  <td id="username"><?php echo $team->username;?></td>
                  <td id="full_name"><?php echo $rs->user->first_name;?></td>
                  <td>
                      <video class="video" width="200" height="100">
                        <source src="<?php echo $rs->user->profile_video;?>" type="video/mp4">
                        Your browser does not support the video.
                      </video>
                </td>
                  <td id="about"><?php echo $team->about;?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $team->created;?></td>
                  <td id="status"><?php echo $status;?></td>
                  <td><select class="action">
                      <option>-Select-</option>
                      <option value="1" >Active</option>
                      <option value="0">Inactive</option>
                      <option value="edit">Edit</option>
                      <option value="4">Delete</option>
                  </select></td>
                </tr>
```

**java script :**

```
$('.action').on("change",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
var def=$(this);
var select=$(this).val();
var username=$(this).closest("tr").children('td#username').text();
var full_name=$(this).closest("tr").children('td#full_name').text();
var about=$(this).closest("tr").children('td#about').text();


// Active Inactive Delete

if( select ==='0' || select ==='1' || select ==='4'){
    $.ajax({
      method: 'post',
      url:'<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>',
      data:{
        action: 'update_member',
        username : username,
        select : select,
      },
      success:function(response){
            if(response != ''){

            var obj = JSON.parse(response);


                // if inactive
                if(obj.action =='0')
                {
                  def.closest("tr").children('td#status').html('<label class="label label-danger">Inactive</label>');
                }
                 // if active
                if(obj.action =='1')
                {
                  def.closest("tr").children('td#status').html('<label class="label label-success">Inactive</label>');
                }
                 // if Delete
                if(obj.action =='4')
                {
                  def.closest("tr").remove();
                }
          }else{
            alert('Inactive Member First ');
          }
     }
    });

}



})
```

**And the Ajax Call Back :**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_update_member', 'update_member_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_update_member', 'update_member_callback');

function update_member_callback(){

global $wpdb;

  $update =$wpdb->update('wp_frankly_team', array('status'=>$_REQUEST['select']), array('username'=>$_REQUEST['username']));
  if($update>0){echo json_encode(array('status'=>'updated', 'action'=>$_REQUEST['select']));}

  wp_die();

}
```

Now my problem is when i have select active or inactive action through select box its working very fine , but when i have select delete option its through error . its not working if the status is in active . but working fine with inactive state . please view the screenshot and tell me where i have don my mistake . i have not add any condition for that

**screen 1 :**
You can see that when i have select action 'delete' for kakulsarma its through error and ajax doesnot thtough any response 2) bombay girl will be delete if i have select 'delete' on action but "kakulsarma will be  delete after selecting 'inactive'

[image: 1)]

**Screen 2 :**

You can see the two ajax request first one is for 'inactive' and second one is for 'delete' and result is kakulsarma is deleted ...

[image]

Why this happning ?

Comment: Use dataType: "json" with your ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.action').on("change",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var def=$(this);
    var select=$(this).val();
    var username=$(this).closest("tr").children('td#username').text();
    var full_name=$(this).closest("tr").children('td#full_name').text();
    var about=$(this).closest("tr").children('td#about').text();


    // Active Inactive Delete

    if( select ==='0' || select ==='1' || select ==='4'){
        $.ajax({
          method: 'post',
          url:"<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>",//change this
          data:{
            action: 'update_member',
            username : username,
            select : select,
          },
          success:function(response){
                if(response != ''){

                var obj = JSON.parse(response);


                    // if inactive
                    if(obj.action =='0')
                    {
                      def.closest("tr").children('td#status').html('<label class="label label-danger">Inactive</label>');
                    }
                     // if active
                    if(obj.action =='1')
                    {
                      def.closest("tr").children('td#status').html('<label class="label label-success">Inactive</label>');
                    }
                     // if Delete
                    if(obj.action =='4')
                    {
                      def.closest("tr").remove();
                    }
              }else{
                alert('Inactive Member First ');
              }
         }
        });

    }
   }); //Add semicolon here.
```

I think it might be work.

Comment: do you understand what happening ?

Comment: delete row is working if the status is inactive else through error :(

Comment: use semicolon at the end of your chnage function and try replace url with this `url:"<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>"`

Comment: finally got the answer . there are no error in my code  . i have try to delete already deleted row .

Comment: @kakulshrama okay . But next time carefull these kind of stuff.